# 'Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments' when trying to edit/delete new entry

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to delete the logged in users document when my app is first loaded. However, if I create a new entry, long press the new entry from the table view and select delete, I get a crash. I thought it had something to do with the document ID not being saved but I couldn't figure out why. If the same newly created entry is deleted after the app is closed and reopened then it will delete with no problem, but if I leave the app open and delete immediately after creating a new document, it will crash. [image: Firestore]

```
class BudgetViewController: UIViewController: {


     var budgetData = [Transaction]()
     func showAdd() {
     
        let modalViewController = AddCategory()
        modalViewController.addCategoryCompletion = { newCategories in
            self.budgetData.append(newCategories)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
            modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
             modalViewController.selectionDelegate = self
             present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

     @objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.tableView)
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
                let cell = CategoryCell()
                var data = budgetData[indexPath.row]
           
                let modalViewController = EditCategory()
                modalViewController.deleteCategory = { row in
                    self.deletedRow = row
                    self.deleteRow()
                }
                modalViewController.documentID = data.trailingSubText ?? ""
                modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                 present(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                modalViewController.row = indexPath.row
                print("longpressed\(indexPath.row)\(data.trailingSubText)")
               
            }
        }
    }
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        loadNewData()
    }
      func loadNewData() {
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        db.collection("users").document(user).collection("Category").getDocuments() {
                snapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {

                        let data = document.data()
                        let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                        let uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                        let documentID = document.documentID
                   //     let timeStamp = data["timeStamp"] as? Date

                        let newSourse = Transaction(title: title, dateInfo: "0% out of spent", image: UIImage.gymIcon, amount: 12, annualPercentageRate: 12, trailingSubText: documentID, uid: uid)
                        self.budgetData.append(newSourse)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    
                }
            }
        }

     class AddCategory: UIViewController {
        @objc func saveAction(){
      
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        let newCategory = Transaction(title: textField.text ?? "", dateInfo: "0% out of spent", image: UIImage.gymIcon, amount: 12, annualPercentageRate: 23, trailingSubText: "", uid: uid)
       
        
       db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("Category").addDocument(data: newCategory.dictionary)

        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                    self.addCategoryCompletion?(newCategory)
        })
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        print("selected")
   
       }
      }
     }

       class EditCategory: UIViewController {
    func deleteAction(){
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

        print("document::\(self.documentID)")
      //  let budget = textField.text
        
        db.collection("users").document(user).collection("Category").document(documentID).delete { (err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                
                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                    self.deleteCategory?(self.row)
                })
                
                print("deleted successfully")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is strongly suggesting that `user` is nil or empty at the time you run this code:

```
guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
db.collection("users").document(user).collection("Category").getDocuments()
```

This almost certainly means that a user was not signed in at the time.  Your code needs to check `currentUser` for nil before trying to access its uid property.  nil means that no user is currently signed in.

The user will not be signed in immediately at app launch.  You should [use an auth state listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517419/right-way-to-implement-firebase-auth-with-state-listener-swift-5) to get a callback when the user object becomes available.

Comment: inside of viewDidLoad for the BudgetViewController() I am printing user.uid, and it is showing the users uid. Its when I try to create a new entry and then return to the BudgetViewController(), long press a table view to delete the entry, that I get the crash. But when I long press on an entry that is already there, it is deleting just fine.

Comment: Log the value of uid just before you use it, in both queries here.  Don't depend on a prior log.

Comment: The uid seems to be returning correctly, I ran a print statement on each function it is being used and each one returns correctly.

Comment: After running some more print statements I am seeing that print(documentID) is returning nil on newly created entries.

Comment: If you have a new problem, that should be posted in a new question.  What you have now doesn't sound related the error message in the title of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best approach, but it is working now. I called

```
    self.budgetData.removeAll()
    self.loadNewData()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

inside of my callback

```
        modalViewController.addCategoryCompletion = { newCategories in
        self.budgetData.append(newCategories)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the presented code, when a new category is added to Firebase

```
let newCategory = Transaction(title: textField.text ?? ...)
db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("Category").addDocument(data: newCategory
```

you're not getting a valid documentId from Firebase first. So therefore that object exists in your dataSource with no documentId so when you try to remove it, there's a crash.

A couple of options

Option 1: Create a firebase reference first, which will provide a Firebase documentId that you can add to the object when writing. See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document). Like this

```
let newCategoryRef = db.collection("Category").document()
let docId = newCategoryRef.documentId
...add docId to the category object, then add to dataSource
```

or

Option 2: Add an observer to the node (see [Realtime Updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)) so when a new document is written, the observers event will fire and present the newly added document, which will contain a valid documentId, and then craft an category object based on that data and add that object to your dataSource array. In this case, you don't need to add it to the dataSource array when writing as it will auto-add after it's written based on the observers .added event.